# Characterizing set of all continuous mappings $f:[0,1] \to \{0,1,2,3,4\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

How can one characterize the set of all continuous mappings of

$$f:[0,1] \to \{0,1,2,3,4\}$$

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a mapping. I know that f is continuous in a point $a \in X$ if

$(a)$ for every neighborhood $U$ of $f(a)$ the inverse image $f^{-1}(U)$ is a neighborhood of $a$ in $X$.

$(b)$ $ f$ is continuous in every point $a \in X$

But I don't know what exactly needs to be done to characterize the set...

Comment: With respect to which topologies?

Comment: One can approach the problem through the relationship between continuous functions and connectedness: prove that the image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected. So the image of [0,1] under $f$ must be a singleton set. So $f$ is constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the discrete topology on $\lbrace 0,1,2,3,4\rbrace$, then $\lbrace x\rbrace$ is a neighborhood of $x\in Y$, so if you consider the sets $f^{-1}(\lbrace x\rbrace)$ for $x=0,\dots, 4$ you should have a partition of $[0,1]$ where all sets are open in $[0,1]$. The only way to respect this is to have all of them empty except for one which is $[0,1]$, and thus your function is constant.